# How is the Apple Watch ECG disabled in certain countries?

Tags: apple-watch, internationalization, health.app

In Japan there will not be ECG for potentially many years until it makes it through mountains of bureaucracy.

I haven't tried a different Apple ID to enable the ECG, but I heard others have tried without any luck.

I heard the block is serial number geo-fenced.  It's obviously not a different WatchOS version. What happens if I factory restore in an approved country?

When Japan or other countries approve ECG existing watches will suddenly have ECG so how will it be enabled?

Do you think this is simply a matter of setting the region, pairing a blocked Japanese watch to an American iPhone and using an American Apple ID?

Comment: For Japan, one year, four months and three days was the wait...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would expect the opposite mechanism that what your title says - empirical evidence shows ECG is disabled everywhere by default and only enabled where cleared. This is also observed for COVID-19 location tracking. It’s baked in to iOS but enabled selectively by Apple in specific regions.

Also, what matters is the countryApple sent the watch to be sold and not where the watch is today or registered post purchase.

If you depend on certain region-based features, please ensure you purchase the device from an authorized seller in your desired country of service and watch for gray market imports or cross-border resale items.

For example, warchOS 7.3 expands ECG in Japan, Mayotte, Philippines, and Thailand. Irregular heart rhythm notifications are now available in Japan, Mayotte, Philippines, Taiwan, and Thailand.

---

Behind the scenes, I expect this activation happens once which writes a configuration profile so the OS can read the value from the Secure Enclave which makes it tamper resistant and survive iOS restores or other regional settings.

For most iOS based restrictions, Apple pins the country for the OS specific features to the sales process. Each serialized product gets sold in a specific location which then lights up the features intended for each region.

When Apple chooses to add the feature to a new location, it would push a software update to interpret the stored values differently and not that it would change the value of the “sold-in” region within the Secure Enclave.

If this is the mechanism, a theoretical jailbreak could easily enable ECG by patching the routine that checks for a valid region even if it can’t change the record of sale stored on the device.

I would open a direct Apple support request for them to explain to you why you can’t change your region if that’s something you can do or have done, but I wouldn’t expect them to re-purpose a device sold in another region for legal and possibly also significant logistical reasons.

Comment: Pins? As in "assign"? Well, don't we already know that certain model numbers and SNs are sold in different countries?  You say they "light up the feature". Well, yea. I'm writing the question to find out how they enable the feature and how is it disabled? It certainly isn't a simple matter of buying the watch in Japan and then pairing it with my North American iPhone and then like magic it works. I'm not the first person since watch series 4 to try. I personally do not have a Japanese watch to try it on yet. I might buy one this week.

Comment: If they log [which they do] the sales location of every single device then it is trivial for Apple to lock or unlock any given feature deep inside the OS, way below any user-accessible tweak. By the same token, the instant Japan, or anywhere, gets the necessary legalese sorted out, Apple can unlock them all overnight. A jailbreak might be able to do it, but nothing short of that.

Comment: Which would mean it is SN geo-fenced. SSH should remedy that no?

Comment: I would be very surprised if this wasn’t part of activation where the location gets stored permanently in the Secure Enclave.  There wouldn’t be any geo location needed after activation, just the API reads a Boolean or country code and enables the features that were assigned to a database of serial numbers (or equivalent opaque assigned ID that can be dissociated with you as a person similar time how differential privacy seeks to avoid databases with identifiable identities in them.) sadly I have neither empirical evidence other than it works in the US nor reverse engineered this function.

Comment: Therefore gaining root would also be futile?

Comment: Jailbreak would likely allow you to change the code logic (hack the code and not the value itself) to get the feature enabled. @tymac But I would guess you can’t change the actual value without Apple enabling your modification. Even a service swap would likely be restricted back to what the original purchase set in motion.

Comment: Bmike thanks for your answer. Since this is speculation and I'm waiting for someone who might know for sure, I'm not sure what the etiquette is. Then again, if someone knows for sure they probably cannot say for legal reasons. But someone who has already jail broken a watch or a pen-tester might be able to answer. For now I will upvote your answer and wait for a definitive answer.

Comment: @Edison I’ve removed the speculation - we have empirical evidence of this not only for ECG but for COVID-19 - your question is quite specific and general and illuminates how Apple is delivering differential services to geographic regions.

Comment: Thanks. Would love to see if someone could setup a server to spoof this. Some guy in Taiwan actually built his own cellular network in his lab to test this in his research.

Comment: @Edison People do it all the time - they set up entire networks to replicate Apple registration servers to get around activation lock. It’s quite impressive how they reverse engineer the communications and set up just enough of a server response to fake out iOS to think it’s phoning home... Basically, you set up your own 17.0.0.0 to start and then plug any other holes you discover. It’s a cat and mouse game as apple discovers how people avoid phone-home then they both change the systems and code.

Answer (score 9):

[According to a](https://9to5mac.com/2018/10/29/apple-watch-ecg-availability/) few [2018 articles](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/12/06/apple-watch-ecg-no-us-region-changing/), the restrictions are based on the region where the watch was sold, and the removal of blocks is implemented by a [watchOS update](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209085).

Not tied to ID. No geo-fence.

There was speculation that changing the watch's region settings could bypass the restriction, but those articles correct that understanding.

Given these facts, the easiest way, and the way that fits the common programming design patterns, to restrict by region would be to disable globally, and with an OS update, enable the feature for the regionally purchased devices, likely by serial number/factory code.

---

As for which watchOS features are enabled for which country, [Apple provides this handy list](https://www.apple.com/uk/watchos/feature-availability/). The UK is listed as an approved country for ECG since [watchOS 5.2](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209085#52) (March 27, 2019).

Comment: Fabulous links! So if Apple stores the region codes we’ll enough, code updates could the light this up (or shut them down) without needing to change the sold to region wherever it’s stored. (My bet is it’s in the Secure Enclave)

Comment: Also, feel free to take any or all of my words from my answer to augment your answer. I think yours is technically better with links.

Comment: Hey, all great answers but since we are now talking about the SEP and Jailbreaking for SSH, this is now getting into Information Security territory as I imagined it would. I'm wondering if an authentication expert over in the other Stack Exchange wouldn't have more concrete information?   Technically speaking, since the ECG block is done by SN, this is a form of geofencing.

Comment: @tymac this is not a security question. This is not a form of geofencing. This isn't even a form of authentication.

Comment: I think if we're talking about the Secure Enclave it's a security topic. Hence the word "secure"

Comment: Storing a configuration item in a secure enclave does not make what the configuration item is used for suddenly about security.