# How to enable COVID-19 Exposure Logging in India

Tags: iphone, ios

How to enable Privacy => Health => COVID-19 Exposure Logging on a iPhone 6S+ device running 13.5.1 in India. Whatever Region I choose, it seems to be disabled and it mentions that its not enabled for the region.

We are developing an App using the Exposure Notification specification but aren't in a position to enable the above attribute

Comment: You have to install the Covid 19 tracking app for India if such an app exists. The app has to be released by your government in detail the ministry of health. If they have not yet released such an app you can't use the tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Non developers don’t get to enable COVID-19 logging in ares where Apple hasn’t enabled it.

Apple has documented volumes of technical data, reasoning, white papers and more: https://www.apple.com/covid19/contacttracing

If that’s not enough to get you going, since you are developing, you do have an avenue that all consumers lack. Open a developer support ticket with Apple using your developer account to get access to a pre-release OS and register any requests that support development of an app before it’s rolled out.

- https://developer.apple.com

That’s the best way to move forward on this if you can’t wait for it to be rolled into the production OS for your region or you want to see the beta SDK / API so you know what is coming as opposed to what shipped. Also, look at WWDC dates - since that is less than 20 days away, you might wait quite some time for an answer or have to rely on the developer forums / documentation already written as there’s a lot in the air right now on the development side.

Comment: I just want the logging capability to be enabled, does that mean the phone needs to be physically within US or Canada. What if you want to build the App from a non US location?

Comment: I’m not going to answer for Apple @Rpj - the developer forums are the place to get your dev questions answered. would it help if I edit in you can not do this without Apple’s help? I understand you want to build your app and think you should engage the developer team for the best chance to do that. No matter where you are, US or non-US. You need pre-release access and guidance to proceed if the public documentation doesn’t help you out enough.

Answer (score 0):

The link https://covid19.apple.com/screening/ appears on apple.com when the country (at the page's bottom) is the US.

Moreover, a lot of content there is US centred.

If you switch to https://www.apple.com/in/, the screening strip at the top disappears. So I think it's not supported in India.

It will not be hugely successful either since the number of iPhones per unit people is less in India than in the US. Stick to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aarogya_Setu .

Comment: If I set my device Region as US should this not work, as I need for building an App using the spec not as end user

Comment: @Rpj no - setting the region should not work as you expect - the region translates some elements of the UI and system for regional preferences. It neither alters what region to which the device is coded at sale nor the functions that are enabled in some geographical regions. See this thread for more details how Apple enables heath related functions - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370827/how-is-the-apple-watch-ecg-disabled-in-certain-countries