# ECG Setup in Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

I have installed latest iOS version on my iPhone as well as on Apple Watch. However I don’t see set up option for ECG app in Health app in iPhone. What do I do.

Comment: Which series watch are you using?

Comment: Also, [which country was your watch intended to be sold into](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370830/5472) when Apple shipped it to the first buyer?

Answer (score 1):

ECG availability depends on where you live.

Apple has a list at https://www.apple.com/lae/watchos/feature-availability/#branded-ecg

Comment: One needs an Apple Watch series 4 or better, too.